# create a pointer to existing llvm::Value and pass the pointer to a function?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am writing a llvm pass which would store variables to a log.

Suppose that the program has a FILE * file object.

Then I want to instrument the following call statement into the program.

`mystore(&file);`

The mystore function has the following style.

```
void mystore(int v){
    //save v 
}
```

How should I write the pass?

Answer (score 1):

A Value does not have an address. Things that exist in RAM have addresses, Values aren't guaranteed to exist in RAM. If they do exist, they're not guaranteed have a single address. Values probably exist somewhere in the computer at the end of the compilation, but passes are free to optimise them away, or turn them into two or more other Values, or or replace several Values by one.

There are two specific kinds of Value that have/are an address: [GlobalValue](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalValue.html) and [AllocaInst](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1AllocaInst.html). In both cases, the Value itself is the address you want for your instrumentation. Most of the interesting Values in a program aren't going to be of these types, though.

So, in other words, you're barking up the wrong tree. You need to take a step back and think clearly about your problem. I suggest working through the Kaleidoscope tutorial first, then looking for a more suitable approach to solve your problems.